# Set .net version in a visual studio c++ project using Common Language Runtime Support

Tags: .net, visual-c++, clr, managed

I have a visual studio 2019 C++ v142 project with Common Language Runtime Support enabled. The project uses the msclr interop to use a .Net dll. The current .Net dll is version 4.0. The project does not have a specific .net version in the vcxproj file.

I upgraded the .Net dll to a newer version, this depends on .Net 4.6.2. So I added the 4.6.2 targeting pack, rebooted, updated the .NET Target Framework Version to v4.6.2 via the project properties, and added a reference to the new dll.

vcxproj entry:

```
...
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
...
```

Compiling it gives an error

```
Warning MSB3274: The primary reference "XXX" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".
```

It still looks for .NET 4.0, which is the lowest version installed, and seem to ignore `TargetFrameworkVersion`.

The project also automatically uses the 4.0 mscorlib.

[image]

According to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp?view=msvc-160 the default should be 4.7.2 for 2019, so I assume it is supported by 2019.

I can not find any 4.0 references in the project or solution. And as it is a C++ project you can not retarget it .NET wise.

Is there a global setting in visual studio, .NET, or the OS where you can change the default .NET? Where is this behavior changed?

Comment: Hard to guess how this could have gone wrong.  Why would you obfuscate to "XXX" in the error message?  Sounds to me you've got *two* C++/CLI projects, and the error message appears in one you haven't upgraded yet.  Yes, there is such a setting: Project > Properties > Advanced > .NET Target Framework Version.  You must close and re-open the solution after changing it to make the IDE aware of the changed references.

Comment: Thanks, correct there are two projects in the solution with clr enabled. Project > Properties > Advanced > .NET Target Framework Version is set to v4.6.2 for both. I moved the code to server with VS2022, it compiles but it uses mscorlib for 4.7.2, even with 4.6.2 as the target framework. Feels like something in the solution or project

Comment: Uninstalled VS2019, installed VS2022 with v142 C++/CLI, then it compiles. Still feels like a weird workaround.